# Missing required but installed gems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-2

My application works fine on my personnal computer, now it's time to deploy !

I try from several hours to deploy my Rails 2 application to a mutualized server. I precise I have not so much permissions on the server, but the vendor says I can run Rails applications.

My config/environment.rb contains 8 config.gem.
This is what I got when I run "script/console production" (the real list is the 8 gems)

```
Missing these required gems:
  will_paginate  = 2.3.16
  ...
```

But I just installed this gems !

```
# gem list -l will_paginate
  *** LOCAL GEMS ***
  will_paginate (2.3.16)
```

I don't know where the bug can be...
Here is some complementary informations:

```
# which ruby
  /usr/bin/ruby
# which gem
  /usr/bin/gem
```

I have some pre-defined folders related to Rails on my home (~):

```
~/.gem/specs/gemcutter.org%80/
~/.gem/specs/rubygems.org%80/
~/ruby/bin/gem
~/ruby/gems/ (with bin, cache, doc, gems and specifications subfolders)
~/ruby/gems/gems/will_paginate-2.3.16/ << my gem !
~/ruby/lib/
```

This is my first deploy and I don't know what to check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution in this page :
http://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/5673

The GEM_PATH was not the right one. So I add this line to my config/environment.rb, everything works perfectly !

```
ENV['GEM_PATH'] = '/home/xxx/ruby/gems'
```

Answer (score 1):

"It works on my computer" is a common problem in any technology....

I'm new to Ruby and discovered two invaluable tools for managing my development and subsequent production environments:

- [rvm](https://rvm.io/)
- [bundler](http://gembundler.com/)

Doesn't solve your immediate issue, but perhaps might be helpful in re-creating your development setup.

Comment: My application works already in a RVM, with the same Ruby/Rails configuration than the server. Bundler is only here to automatically install gems from the config file ; gems are installed but not linked in ruby execution.